# Como inicializar dois ou mais seletores de data diferentes em um formulário com Materialize?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, materialize

Após inicializar um `datepicker` do Materialize CSS com sucesso, percebi que precisaria de dois `datepickers` no mesmo formulário. O problema é que só consigo inicializar um `datepicker`:

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="ngSubmit()">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="enter_at"
      type="text"
      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
      class="datepicker"/>
    <label for="enter_at">Entrou em:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
      <input
        id="exit_at"
        type="text"
        placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
        class="datepicker"/>
    <label for="exit_at">Saiu em:</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-large blue pf-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Inicialização do componente no Angular:**

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        this.dataForm.controls['enter_at'].setValue(dateText);
    },
});
```

Tentei inicializar eles apenas ao clicar, mas não deu certo. O sistema simplesmente ignora a propriedade:

**HTML modificado**:

```
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="enter_at"
      type="text"
      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
      (click)="datapickerInitialize('enter_at')"
      class="datepicker"/>
    <label for="enter_at">Entrou em:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
      <input
        id="exit_at"
        type="text"
        placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
        (click)="datapickerInitialize('enter_at')"
        class="datepicker"/>
    <label for="exit_at">Saiu em:</label>
  </div>
```

**Função `datapickerInitialize`**:

```
datapickerInitialize(id: string){
  var elems = document.getElementById(id);
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    onSelect: (dateText) => {
      this.dataForm.controls[id].setValue(dateText);
    },
  });
}
```

Não estou fazendo uso do jQuery no projeto por causa de alguns conflitos de manipulação do DOM com alguns componentes.

Como fazer essa inicialização no JavaScript ou TypeScript puro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar trocando o tipo de evento, de `(click)` para `(focus)`:

```
<div class="input-field">
  <input
    id="enter_at"
    type="text"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    (focus)="datapickerInitialize('enter_at')"
    class="datepicker"/>
  <label for="enter_at">Entrou em:</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <input
    id="exit_at"
    type="text"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    (focus)="datapickerInitialize('enter_at')"
    class="datepicker"/>
  <label for="exit_at">Saiu em:</label>
</div>
```

A funcionalidade passou a operar com sucesso.